# Load Angular components by router state change

Tags: angular, router

in Angular all components packed in one file and loading all at once
so **main.bundle.js** getting bigger with any new component
is there any way to load needed components async, when router state changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { EagerComponent } from './eager.component';

const routes: Routes = [
   { path: '', redirectTo: 'eager', pathMatch: 'full' },
   { path: 'eager', component: EagerComponent },
   { path: 'lazy', loadChildren: 'lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule' }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

For further information look into Lazy Loading here: 
https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html

Comment: yep, that's it. but it loads module with its own routing